# NullPointer Exception while executing two test classes in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

I have created two test classes. The login test class is dependant on the Setting test class. So, I have used `dependsOnMethods` annotation and extends setting class in Login test. But while executing both test classes through TestNG, the setting test executed successfully but it gives null pointer exception at the point when the second test class executes.

The test class executes fine individually.

**Class 1: Setting code**

```
package com.selenium.tests;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import com.selenium.pageObjects.SignIn;
import com.selenium.pageObjects.DashBoard;
import com.selenium.pageObjects.Setting;
import com.selenium.resources.base;

import junit.framework.Assert;

public class SettingTest extends base {

    public WebDriver driver;
    SignIn signIn;
    String getTitle;

    public static Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(SettingTest.class.getName());

    @BeforeTest
    public void intializeDriver() throws IOException {
        System.out.println("before Test");

        driver = browserIntilization();

        driver.get(prop.getProperty("Application_url"));
        log.info("Application is opened");
        
    }

    @Test
    public void Dealer_to_set_the_app_configuration() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("1st Test");

        Setting sourceLogin = new Setting(driver);
        Select market = selectFunction(sourceLogin.getMarket());
        market.selectByVisibleText("USA");
        log.info("market is selected");

        Select language = selectFunction(sourceLogin.getlanguage());
        language.selectByVisibleText("English");

        log.info("Language is Selected");

        signIn = sourceLogin.getSignIn();
        Thread.sleep(5000);

         getTitle = signIn.getPageTitle();

        Assert.assertEquals("ICAR-X", getTitle);
        log.info("User redirected to Login Page Successfully.");

    }
    
    


    @AfterTest
    public void tearDown() {
        System.out.println("After Test Executed");
        driver.quit();

    }

}
```

**class 2: Login Code**

```
package com.selenium.tests;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import com.selenium.pageObjects.DashBoard;

import junit.framework.Assert;

public class LoginTest extends SettingTest{
    
    @Test (dependsOnMethods = ("Dealer_to_set_the_app_configuration"))
    public void Dealer_enters_valid_credential_to_login_inside_the_app() throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("2nd test");
        
        signIn.getDealerID("70052");
        log.info("DealerID is entered successfully");
        signIn.getUserID("x579303");
        log.info("userID is entered successfully");
        signIn.getPassword("Nissan#2020");
        log.info("password is entered successfully");
        DashBoard dashboard = signIn.getDashBoard();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        dashboard.getPageTitle();
        Assert.assertEquals("ICAR-X", getTitle);
        log.info("User redirected to Dashboard Page Successfully.");
        
    }

}
```

**Error**

```
[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 7.3.0
ERROR StatusLogger No Log4j 2 configuration file found. Using default configuration (logging only errors to the console), or user programmatically provided configurations. Set system property 'log4j2.debug' to show Log4j 2 internal initialization logging. See https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html for instructions on how to configure Log4j 2
before Test
Starting ChromeDriver 85.0.4183.87 (cd6713ebf92fa1cacc0f1a598df280093af0c5d7-refs/branch-heads/4183@{#1689}) on port 40014
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
[1602609611.367][WARNING]: This version of ChromeDriver has not been tested with Chrome version 86.
Oct 13, 2020 10:50:13 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
1st Test
1st Test
After Test Executed
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.selenium.resources.base.getScreenShotPath(base.java:78)
    at com.selenium.listeners.Listeners.onTestFailure(Listeners.java:53)
    at org.testng.internal.TestListenerHelper.runTestListeners(TestListenerHelper.java:96)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.runTestResultListener(TestInvoker.java:220)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:832)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:147)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:764)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:585)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:384)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:378)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:337)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:286)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1218)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1140)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1069)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1037)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
```

**Baseclass code**

```
package com.selenium.resources;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;

public class base {
    public WebDriver driver;
    public Properties prop;

    public WebDriver browserIntilization() throws IOException {

        prop = new Properties();
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(
                System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\src\\test\\java\\com\\selenium\\resources\\properties.Properties");
        prop.load(fis);

        String browsername = prop.getProperty("browser");
        

        if (browsername.equals("safari")) {

            driver = new SafariDriver();

        } else if (browsername.equals("chrome")) {

            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
                    System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\browser_Servers\\chromedriver.exe");
            driver = new ChromeDriver();

        } else if (browsername.equals("firefox")) {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver",
                    System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\browser_Servers\\geckodriver.exe");
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        } else {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver",
                    System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\browser_Servers\\IEDriverServer.exe");
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        }

        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        return driver;

    }
    
    public  Select selectFunction(WebElement element) {
        
        Select select = new Select(element);
        
        return select;
        
    }
    
    public String getScreenShotPath(String testCaseName, WebDriver driver) throws IOException
    {
        TakesScreenshot ts=(TakesScreenshot) driver;
        File source =ts.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        String destinationFile = System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\screenShots\\"+testCaseName+".png";
        FileUtils.copyFile(source,new File(destinationFile));
        return destinationFile;


    }
    
    
    
        

    
    
}
```

Comment: can you pose your base class code? it looks like the null pointer is on the getScreenshotPatch method on the base class.

Comment: I have added the base class code. It is running fine individually but facing issues with when executing them together.

Comment: Why do you pass the driver object to the screenshot method? the driver is initialized from this base class and it is public. Try adding null check to the driver object on this method. I think , the browser may have been already closed,  but you are trying to take screenshot in this case driver will be null.

Answer (score 0):

Please post your testng.xml here, it seems that your test case : **Setting code** is running 2 times and that's because as per the console output you have shared it is showing the syso message "1st Test" for 2 times and as you have used driver.quit() in your @AfterTest annotation then your **second test** : Login Code wont run as driver.quit() will terminate all running sessions of browser.

**Quick Solution** : *Testng.xml*

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >

<suite name="AsPerNeed">

    <test name="Setting code">
        <classes>
            <class name="package.class 1" />
            
        </classes>
    </test>

    <test name="Login code`">  
        <classes>
            <class name="package.class 2" />
            
        </classes>
    </test>
    
</suite>
```

remove @AfterTest annotation from you first test class and user @AfterSuit annotation in your baseclass like below.

```
@AfterSuite
    public void tearDown() {
        driver.quit();

    }
```